# finding out the mapping of the subring inside another ring

Tags: commutative-algebra

I was reading the book on Commutative Algebra by Miles Reid and during the discussion of the zero divisors the authors make the following comment.

The ring $K[X,Y]/(XY)$ is a subring of  $k[X] \oplus  k[Y]$ with X  and Y mapping to a non zero divisor and zero so that the product is zero.

The question is if the ring is a subring then which extra elements are there in $k[X] \oplus k[Y]$. What is the mapping ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your direct sum $\oplus$ denotes the product $\times$ of rings. Furthermore any ring is a subring of itself.

In this case there is a well defined morphism of rings
$k[X,Y]\rightarrow k[X]\times k[Y]$
induced by the assignments $X\mapsto (X,0)$ and $Y\mapsto (0,Y)$. It is clearly surjective and its kernel is given by the ideal $(XY)$. By the first isomorphism theorem $k[X,Y]/(XY) \cong k[X] \times k[Y]$.